# How do I determine if a device is a desktop browser?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive design for a website.  We have a rollover navigation menu for non-touch desktop browsers and an off canvas menu design for touch mobile and touch tablets.  It is an ASP.NET MVC4 project.  How can I determine in C#, Javascript, or CSS3 if a user is browsing the site with a desktop browser?  I would prefer to use some kind of CSS3 media query if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a beautiful site: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/

```
 var isMobile = {
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Opera: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
        },
        Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function() {
            return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
        }
    };

    if(isMobile.any()){
        // Mobile!
    } else {
        // It is desktop
    }
```

Else use libraries like device.js http://matthewhudson.me/projects/device.js/

Comment: That is really cool.  After seeing the code above, my question would be, what would Nook, Kindle Fire, and Microsoft Surface tablets return?

Comment: This is the reason why I suggested using device.js or any other standard library. Even they can not test for everything under the sun(tizen, nook, kindle etc) but this is the only method I know so far to detect desktop.